# What are Gradle - Script block details

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I want to understand structure of the build.gradle file, in particular Script block details part.

Here a simple example:

```
buildscript {
}

allprojects {
}

// Custom defined method that will be invoked from other parts of the script
def xmethod() {
}

subprojects {
}
```

I understand that the *xMethod(){}* is a method defined in Groovy.

But what are all other "Script block details" like allprojects and subprojects, ...? What constructs in Gradle they represent? How are they being executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things are in play here.

1. In groovy if you define a method:

```
def foo(Closure c) {
  ...
}
```

this method can be called in two ways:

```
foo({ println "hello world" })
```

or since the last parameter defined for the method is a closure, you can also call it like this:

```
foo { 
  println "hello world"
}
```

2. when gradle executes a `build.gradle` file, it does so in [lifecycle phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html). I would recommend reading through that section to get a feel for the process. In general, all the `allprojects { ... }` etc blocks will be executed in the configuration phase which is run before any of your tasks are run. The `buildscript { ... }` block is as far as I understand it a special case where gradle builds the classpath for the `build.gradle` file itself and it is executed in a special phase before anything else.
3. when gradle executes a `build.gradle` file it uses an instance of the [gradle Project class](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) as a "delegate". This means that for any methods which gradle can not find directly in your build file, it will try to find them on the project instance instead.

With all the above, the syntax:

```
buildscript { 

}
```

is actually a method call to a method with the signature `def buildscript(Closure c)` where gradle will first look for this method in your `build.gradle` file and if not found it will look in the project instance and [find the buildscript method there](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#buildscript-groovy.lang.Closure-).

Same goes for all the other calls you mention.

A good place to get an understanding for these is the [gradle dsl reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html) which also points you to the relevant delegate class javadocs (like the project delegate above).

Comment: Thank you for this! Especially point #1. I was scouring the Groovy language document for an hour trying to figure out what language construct corresponded to a name followed by a block. It had not occurred to me that it was just a function call with the parentheses omitted, with one argument that was a closure. Now it all makes sense.

Comment: That last link (Gradle DSL) was exactly what I was looking for to begin to understand a Gradle Groovy script.